# Mongodb find document from multiple collections

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

in nodejs and mongodb, usin mongoose ,

how can I query multiple collections?

for example: I have 3 collections:
mycollection1, mycollection2, mycollection3

I want to create query like findOne or findMany on mycollection*

and the query will return al the documents that exist in those collections

*(the same as I can do in Elasticsearch)

Thanks,
Larry

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$unionWith`

```js
db.coll1.aggregate([
  {
    "$unionWith": {
      "coll": "coll2"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unionWith": {
      "coll": "coll3"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$eq": [
          "$a",
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Test it here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hoSPNAVcnVQ)

Its better to do the filters before the union, and use this(if you have filters) (the above filters after), you can take the `$match` and add it to the each union.

`{ $unionWith: { coll: "<collection>", pipeline: [ <stage1>, ... ] } }`

Comment: I want to query all collections that start with mycoll* , mongodb does not support it?

Comment: i dont think it does, but you can generate this query with application code, its easy to do it.I mean auto-construct the json-query with javascript for example.You can make a fuction that take the collection names, and return a json query with the unions for them.The collections names you can either have it in memory or get them dynamically from the database,for example listCollections of a database,and keep some of them.